# Hold a key to increase trackpad speed in ubuntu？

Tags: gnome, touchpad, multi-touch, scrolling

how to hold a key to increase trackpad speed in ubuntu？I want to multiply the scrolling speed when hold altkey. I tried the imwheel, but the imwheel made my trackpad scroll behaviour very strange,When I installed imwheel, the scroll in my trackpad will add a strange extra movement after I scroll, not like the native behaviour